# Progress bar not displaying when button is clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a `Fileupload` control and when I click the upload button I just wana display an image i.e. Progress bar or Loading gif image. I tried it through javascript but I am unable to show that Image. **I want that Image to be displayed until File gets uploaded.**

This my aspx code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="transbox" id="mainbk" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
            <fieldset style="width:51%; margin-left:300px;font-family:'Palatino Linotype';font-size:large">
            <legend style="color:white;font-family:'Palatino Linotype'">Upload Video Files</legend>
                <asp:FileUpload EnableViewState="true" runat="server" ID="UploadImages" style="background-color:white; position:relative; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium" Width="500px" AllowMultiple="false"/>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFile" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UploadImages" ErrorMessage="Select a File" style="color:red;position:absolute"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
                <asp:Label Text="Description:" runat="server" ID="lbldes" style="font-family:'Palatino Linotype';position:absolute; margin-top:10px; font-size:large;color:white" ></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox id="txtdes" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="60px" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:195px;" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtreq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdes" ErrorMessage="Description Required" style="color:red;position:absolute;margin-top:20px;" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />

                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" style="position:relative; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; width: 112px; height: 29px;" Text="Upload" UseSubmitBehavior="true" OnClick="uploadedFile_Click"/>
                <asp:image id="loading_img" runat="server" style="Display:none;position:absolute;margin-top:-20px;margin-left:200px;" src="../Images/Other Images/waiting.gif" />
            </fieldset>
     </div>
    </form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#uploadedFile').click(function () {
            $('#loading_img').show(); // Show image
            return true; // Proceed with postback
        });
    </script>
```

and this my click event for the button **uploadedFile**, in aspx.cs page.

```
protected void uploadedFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
             string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(UploadImages.FileName).ToLower();
             if (fileExt == ".flv" || fileExt == ".avi" || fileExt == ".mp4" || fileExt == ".3gp" || fileExt == ".mov" || fileExt == ".wmv" || fileExt == ".mpg" || fileExt == ".asf" || fileExt == ".swf")
             {
                try
                {

                    filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Videos/" + UploadImages.FileName);
                    UploadImages.PostedFile.SaveAs(filepath);
                    vurl=UploadImages.FileName.ToString();
                    newpath = "Images//Video_Thumbs//" + createvidImage(filepath);
                    al = txtdes.Text.ToString();
                    id += 1;
                    string Insert = "Insert into video (vid,videoname,videourl,vidthumb) values (@id,@alter,@vrl,@IMAGE_PATH)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Insert, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMAGE_PATH", newpath.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alter", al);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vrl", vurl);
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Video Uploaded!!');", true);

                        txtdes.Text = "";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e1)
                    {
                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('" + e1.Message.ToString() + "!!');", true);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "!!');", true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me out to do this either in javascript or C#.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the way `<asp:Button/>` tags (and all asp tags, for that matter) render in the page. If you right-click and inspect the element, you'll see that its ID isn't actually 'uploadedFile' but probably something like 'ctl00_uploadedFile', and as a result, your jQuery selectors aren't finding the elements. I'd recommend one of two things:

1) Inspect the page and see what the actual rendered element is being named, then update your jQuery accordingly.

2) Use an in-line C# snippet to pull out the ID. For example, you would replace `$('#uploadedFile')` with `$('#' + '<%=uploadedFile.ClientID%>')`. The `<%%>` portion of that will evaluate as C# and insert the ClientID property (i.e. the id value that renders on the page) into the jQuery selector.

**Edit:** Apparently I was mistaken about `<asp:Button/>` tags, and they render with an unaltered `name` property rather than an `id` property. The selector you'd want for the uploadedFile button is `$('input[name="uploadedFile"]')`.

Comment: @Alex... I inspected the page and I found this in the place of button tag..

<input type="submit" name="uploadedFile" value="Upload" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;uploadedFile&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="uploadedFile" style="position:relative; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; width: 112px; height: 29px;">

What does that mean actually and I am also getting an error saying uncaught reference error, $ is not defined..

Comment: Huh. Apparently my answer doesn't apply to <asp:Button> tags. If it's not getting an ID property, then you'll have to select it by name instead. I'll edit my answer accordingly. As for the $ not being defined, either you aren't loading the jQuery source file into the page or the script block is running before that file loads. If it's the latter, I'd suggest wrapping the block in a separate .js file and putting that in the head below the jQuery file.

Comment: @Alex.. I am sorry to say but as I really dnt have much knowledge about jquery, I am asking this wid u.. what kinda jQuery source file we need to write.. Now what I did is I jus added that script block before head tag... but still the result is same... :(

Comment: You'll need to include a jQuery source file in your page, [which you can get here](http://jquery.com/download/). Depending on what browsers you intend to support, you either want 1.10.2 (more compatibility) or 2.0.3 (modern browsers only). Download the production version of whichever you choose, put it somewhere in your site hierarchy, and include it like so in the head of the page: `<script src="[path-to-jquery-file].js"></script>`.

Comment: @Alex.. I have added 1.10.2 jQuery source file.. now I am not finding any error but still the loading image will not be displayed onclick of uploadedFile button.. Is there any other way to do it..

Comment: The image falls under the purview of my original answer (unless the converted `<img>` tag doesn't have an id property either). If it does, then my initial answer adjusted to use 'loading_img' should do what you need. If not, I'm assuming it does the same name property thing the button did, in which case the edited portion of my answer should apply. If it's not either of those cases, let me know what HTML it's creating.

Comment: @Alex.. This is the HTML its creating..

<input type="submit" name="uploadedFile" value="Upload" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;uploadedFile&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="uploadedFile" style="position:relative; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; width: 112px; height: 29px;">

and this is for image....

<img id="loading_img" src="../Images/Other Images/waiting.gif" style="Display:none;position:absolute;margin-top:-20px;margin-left:200px;">

Comment: If it's generating `<img id="loading_img"`, then the answer is even easier - just leave that part of the jQuery alone. `$('#loading_img').show();` should work, and if for some reason it doesn't, try `$('#loading_img').css('display', 'block');` instead.

Comment: @Alex.. No buddy... tried all the possible combinations u mentioned.. But still not able to display the image onclick of the button... :(